# Am I violating an OOP design guideline here? Couple of interesting design pickles

Tags: c++, oop

I'm designing a new power-up system for a game I'm creating. It's a side scroller, the power ups appear as circular objects and the player has to touch / move through them to pick up their power. The power up then becomes activated, and deactivates itself a few seconds later. Each power-up has its own duration defined. For simplicity's sake the power ups are spawned (placed on the screen) every X seconds.

I created a PowerUpManager, a singleton whose job is to decide when to create new power ups and then where to place them.

I then created the Powerup base class, and a class that inherits from that base class for every new Powerup. Every Power-up can be in one of three states: Disabled, placed on the screen, and picked up by the player. If the player did not pick up the power up but moved on, the power up will exit the screen and should go back from the placed state to the disabled state, so it can be placed again.

One of the requirements (that I) put in place is that there should be minimal code changes when I code up a new Power up class. The best I could do was one piece of code: The PowerUpManager's constructor, where you must add the new power-up to the to the container that holds all power-ups:

```
PowerupManager::PowerupManager()
{
    available = {
        new PowerupSpeed(),
        new PowerupAltWeapon(),
        ...
    };
}
```

The PowerUpManager, in more details (Question is coming up!):
Holds a vector of pointers to PowerUp (The base class) called available. This is the initial container that holds one copy of each power up in the game.
To handle the different states, it has a couple of lists: One that holds pointers to currently placed power ups, and another list that holds pointers to currently active power ups.
It also has a method that gets called every game tick that decides if and where to place a new power up and clean up power ups that weren't picked up. Finally it has a method that gets called when the player runs into a power up, that activates the power up (Moves it from the placed to the active list, and calls the power up's activate method).

Finally, once you understand the full picture, the question:
I needed a way for client code to ask if a particular power-up is currently active. For example: The player has a weapon, but there is a power up that replaces that weapon temporarily. Where I poll for input and recognize that the player wants to fire his weapon, I need to call the correct fire method - The alternative weapon power up fire method, and not the regular weapon fire method.

I thought of this particular demand for a while and came up with this:

```
template <typename T>
T* isActivated() // Returns a pointer to the derived Powerup if it exists in the activated list, or nullptr if it doesn't
{
    for(Powerup *i : active) // Active is a list of currently active power ups
    {
        T *result = dynamic_cast<T*>(i);

        if(result)
            return result;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

So client code looks like this:

```
PowerUpAltWeapon *weapon = powerUpManager->isActivated<PowerUpAltWeapon>();
if(weapon)
    ...
```

I thought the solution is elegant and kind of neat, but essentially what it is is trying to convert a base type to a derived type. If that doesn't work, you try the next derived type... A long chain of if / else if, it's just disguised in a loop. Does this violate the guideline that I just described? Not casting a base type to all of its derived types in a long chain of if / else if until you get a hit? Is there another solution?

A secondary question is: Is there a way to get rid of the need to construct all the different power ups in the PowerupManager constructor? That is currently the only place you need to make a change if you want to introduce a new power up. If I can get rid of that, that'd be interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on your design, but if it was me I choose an ID for each PowerUp and a set of IDs in the client, and each time a user posses a PowerUp that ID will be added to its set and ... you know the rest. Using this technique I can do fast look up for every PowerUp and avoid `dynamic_cast`:

```
std::set<PowerUp::ID> my_powerUps;
template< class T > bool isActivated() {
    return my_powerUps.find( T::id() ) != my_powerUps.end();
}
```

And about your second question, I have a similar program that load some plugins instead of `PowerUp`, I have a pure virtual base class that contain all methods that required by that plugin and implement it in shared modules and then at startup I load them from an specific folder. For example each shared module contain a `create_object` that return a `plugin*` (in your case `PowerUp*` of course) and then I iterate the folder, load modules and call `create_object` to create my plugins from them and register them in my `plugin_manager`

Comment: Good one. I can even automatically generate the IDs from the index of each power-up in the original power ups container. Granted, I'd still like some thoughts about my secondary question. If C++ had innate reflection, I could run code that scans the folder of power ups, gets the class names from the .h files and constructs all of those classes.

Comment: Well you probably initialize your game at some point. Why not give your manager a method that allows Powerups to register? Then adding a powerup that uses the base class would only require you to add a new type and register it at initialization time.

Comment: No you can't do that, but you can define a pure virtual base class that have all the operations that used by PowerUp objects and then implement the PowerUps in shared modules(`.DLL` or `.so`) and then load them dynamically and create them from that module

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's an iPhone game, so .dlls are an issue... Regardless, do you have a link to something that explains such a solution? I've never done anything like that and would love to learn more.